# Need clarifying of exit and abort script Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am writing a little practice program with `if` and `else`. The code is as follows:

```
puts "What is your name?"
user_name = $stdin.gets.chomp

print "Hello #{user_name}! Welcome to Puzzles and Riddles v.1!"

puts "There are two doors \n 1. Riddles \n 2. Puzzles. \n Which door do you go through?"
answer_1 = $stdin.gets.chomp
if 
    answer_1 == "1"
    puts "You have taken the Riddle room!"
    print "Here is your riddle: \n You use a knife to slice my head and weep beside me when I am dead. \n What am I?"
    end

    riddle_1_answer = $stdin.gets.chomp

    if 
    riddle_1_answer == ( riddle_1_answer == "An onion" ) || ( riddle_1_answer == "an onion" ) || ( riddle_1_answer == "Onion" ) || ( riddle_1_answer == "onion" )
    puts "The correct answer is: An onion! \n You have advanced to round two."

    else
        puts "Sorry, your answer is incorrect. Think about it."
end

puts "Riddle 2. \n What has 4 fingers and a thumb, but is not living?"

riddle_2_answer = $stdin.gets.chomp
```

Now if the user got `riddle_1_answer` wrong how would I make it so that the program exits/aborts?
I tried adding exit(0) to the else section and it would terminate the program but would also come up with an error. So I'm not sure if the error is causing the program to end or its the exit(0) command

Comment: Is the question really just “how to exit/abort”?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Yeah. Sorry I'm pretty new to Ruby and its my first time using the exit/abort commands.

Comment: Well you don’t have either in your current code. Have you tried using them? Was there a problem when doing so?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Yeah I had tried exit(0) in the else section so if the user got the answer wrong it would abort the program.

Comment: And did that not work?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall it does abort the program but comes up with an error.

Comment: Why is none of this in your question?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall should it be?? Sorry I'm totally new to this website. I don't know what to add and what not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obvious from your question, the sample code, and your answers to @AndrewMarshall, that you need some guidance.

Here you go.

First, ruby is one of many programming languages, and there is a reason why many experienced programmers end up gravitating to it: ruby is object-oriented, expressive, powerful, and reasonably concise without being unnaturally terse.  So, if you are going to learn ruby, learn by reading lots of good ruby code, from which you'll learn good practices.

Second, appearance matters because it impacts or enhances readability and comprehension.  A good appearance lends to improved readability and more rapid comprehension.  A bad appearance does the opposite.

The lack of alignment of the `if`, `else`, and `end` tokens in your code is bad; it made it hard to see the structure of the code's logic.

There are many rules of thumb in programming.  Here are a few such rules that apply to most languages:

- use alignment and indention properly
- always think about "edge cases" (or errors)
- limit and isolate complexity (use functions, modules, classes, & methods)
- Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)

So let's apply those two principles to your code and transform it a bit.

The first two lines:

```
puts "What is your name?"
user_name = $stdin.gets.chomp
```

- What if the user enters CTRL-D (EOF)?
- What if the user enters an empty line?

Is an error acceptable?  An EOF on STDIN returns a `nil`, which causes an error on the `chomp`.

Is an empty string (zero length) name acceptable?  If not, what should we do about it?

When there are complexities on doing something relatively simple, like getting a user name, encapsulate the complexities in a function or method, so the code needing the user name is not made confusing by the complexities of getting it.

Here's a replacement.  First, let's manage the details (and complexities) of getting a user name within a small function.

```
def get_user_name
  name = ''
  while name.size == 0 do
    print "What is your name? "
    name = gets
    exit(1) if name.nil?  # exit program on EOF
    name.strip!
  end
  name
end
```

Notice that we don't use `chomp` on `name` until after we've made sure that it isn't `nil`.  Many programs react to EOF on input by exiting, aborting, or continuing on without any more questions.  In this example, we'll just assume the user wants to quit.

Notice also that we used `strip!` instead of `chomp!`?  That's because `strip!` will remove both leading and trailing whitespace, including the trailing newline.

Notice also that we didn't use `$stdin.gets`, but instead just `gets`?  This is because the default object for `gets` is `$stdin`.

Probably a better approach to managing exceptional situations within small functions (methods), is to `raise` an exception, and let the higher level application logic decide how to manage it.  With that in mind, here is a revised definition:

```
def get_user_name
  name = ''
  while name.size < 1 do
    print "What is your name? "
    name = gets
    raise "End of input" if name.nil?  # raise exception on EOF
    name.strip!
  end
  name
end
```

Now, that `get_user_name` is defined, we can use it wherever we need a user name.  We know that EOFs are managed, and we know that we won't get an empty string.

```
 user_name = get_user_name
```

Now, let's do the rest of your original code, but aligned and indented properly.

```
print "Hello #{user_name}! Welcome to Puzzles and Riddles v.1!"

puts "There are two doors \n 1. Riddles \n 2. Puzzles. \n Which door do you go through?"
answer_1 = $stdin.gets.chomp
if answer_1 == "1"
  puts "You have taken the Riddle room!"
  print "Here is your riddle: \n You use a knife to slice my head and weep beside me when I am dead. \n What am I?"
end

riddle_1_answer = $stdin.gets.chomp

if riddle_1_answer == ( riddle_1_answer == "An onion" ) || ( riddle_1_answer == "an onion" ) || ( riddle_1_answer == "Onion" ) || ( riddle_1_answer == "onion" )
  puts "The correct answer is: An onion! \n You have advanced to round two."

else
  puts "Sorry, your answer is incorrect. Think about it."
end

puts "Riddle 2. \n What has 4 fingers and a thumb, but is not living?"

riddle_2_answer = $stdin.gets.chomp
```

Now that the alignment and indentation is correct, it's easier to see the logic, and its flaws.  It's also easier to see a pattern of logic, and whenever you see a pattern, then DRY it up, and make methods (functions) to encapsulate the repetition.

But first, let's fix the obvious bugs.

The `if` expression is broken. Look at it again, and you'll see this:

```
if riddle_1_answer == TEST1 || TEST2 || TEST3 || TEST4
```

where I've used `TEST`*n* to replace the various case-sensitive tests you had.

This `if` expression will *always* fail because the value of `riddle_1_answer` will *never* be `true` or `false` and the result of the various `TEST`n expressions will always be `true` or `false`.  I'm pretty sure you wanted this:

```
if TEST1 || TEST2 || TEST3 || TEST4
```

Second, when testing for a string value, it's not necessary to test all case variations.  Just `downcase` the answer and test on lowercase test values (unless case-sensitivity is important).  Alternatively, if simple character string tests aren't sufficient, then use a `regular expression` and use the `i` option for case-insensitive matching.  Example:

```
if riddle_1_answer =~ /(?:an )?onion/i
```

Will test for `"an onion"` or `"onion"` in upper, lower, and mixed case.

Perhaps more important than these little errors, one should look to avoid repetition.  The general pattern appears to be:

1. Ask a question
2. Accept an answer
3. Check the answer
4. Change the program state based on the answer
5. Repeat

When you see things like this, you should start thinking of *arrays* and *hashes*.  Arrays are used when the values can be numerically indexed, and hashes are used when you want to get values associated with varying *keys*.  Then, a simple loop can be used to iterate across the values of the array or hash.

So, seeing the pattern above, it becomes more clear that we will need a method to prompt for the question, get the answer, deal with a possible EOF and empty strings, validate non-empty answers, possibly repeating the question & answer when needed.

So let's define a little method to get an answer

```
# prompt_and_get_answer PROMPT, ANSWERS_DATA
#
# issue PROMPT, and get an answer, which must be one of the 
# values in ANSWERS_DATA array, or one of the keys of the 
# ANSWERS_DATA hash.

def prompt_and_get_answer prompt, answers_data
  ans = ''
  while ans.size < 1
    print prompt
    ans = $stdin.gets
    if ans.nil?
      raise "End of input"
    end
    ans.strip!
    if answers_data.class == Hash  # hash?
      answers = answers_data.keys.sort
    else
      answers = answers_data.sort
    end
    matches = answers.grep(/#{ans}/i)  # match possible valid answers
    case matches.size        # how many items found?
    when 0
      puts "#{ans} is not a valid answer.  Use one of:"
      puts answers.join(', ')
      ans = ''
    when 1                   # return the match or the value of the matching key
      ans = answers_data.class == Hash ? answers_data[matches[0]] : matches[0]
    else
      puts "#{ans} is ambiguous; be more specific to match one of:"
      puts answers.join(', ')
      ans = ''
    end
  end
  ans
end
```

Now, we can use this method with a prompt as an argument, and get an answer, knowing that it's not going to be an empty answer and it's not going to be an EOF.

First, let's name the questions, and let's show the prompts as they would appear on output, without using the explicitly escaped newlines (`\n`).

```
$prompt1 = <<EOQ
There are two doors
1. Riddles
2. Puzzles
Which door do you go through?
EOQ
$answer1 = [ '1', '2' ]

$prompt2 = <<EOQ
Here is your riddle:
You use a knife to slice my head and weep beside me when I am dead.
What am I?
EOQ
$answer2 = [ 'onion' ]

ans1 = prompt_and_get_answer $prompt1, $answer1
if ans1 == '1'
  do_riddles
elsif ans1 == '2'
  do_puzzles
else
  raise "Bad answer to prompt1"
end

def do_riddles
  while true
    ans = prompt_and_get_answer $prompt2, $answer2
    if ans == 'onion'
      puts "yay!  you're right!"
      break
    else
      puts "nope.  Try again"
    end
  end
end
```

You can see from this that we've used methods (functions) to break the logic into smaller pieces, and to separate the details of getting answers from the details of testing them.

Later, we can see how to use tables and hashes to build up a list of questions.

Good luck.

Comment: WOW. Thank you sooo much! That cleared up a lot of stuff in my head. Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: And would you have any suggestions on how to learn how to use Ruby better?? Websites,tips,ect.

Comment: codeschool.com, codeacademy.com, railstutorial.org.  Install the rails gem and then go read the code.